# How can I create a stored procedure that returns a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using Entity Framework. I create a function in SQL Server where I'll import to Entity Framework.

In Entity Framework I can't import functions, only stored procedures.

I was reading in the web that a stored procedure can returns values. In this case, I need to return a table. Is it possible to do it?

Example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[X]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
END
GO
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what you mean from your question - please read it to yourself and think if anyone not in your head can understand it. Then re-write it will it can be.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I've updated the description. Thanks

Comment: See this link: http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-select-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a SELECT statement in your stored procedure.  That's the only way that a stored procedure can "return" a table.

Comment: I did it. But SQL Server is still marks RETURNS INT..

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[X]
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT ...
END
GO